# JQ: key selection from numeric objects

Tags: json, jq

I use jq 1.6 in a Windows 10 PowerShell enviroment and trying to select keys from  coincidentally numeric json objects.

Json exampel:

```
    {  
   "alliances_info":{  
      "744085325458334213":{  
         "emblem":3,
         "name":"wellwell",
         "member_count":1,
         "level":1,
         "military_might":1035,
         "public":false,
         "tag":"MELL",
         "slogan":"",
         "id":744085325458334213
      },
      "744128593839677958":{  
         "emblem":0,
         "name":"Brave",
         "member_count":1,
         "level":1,
         "military_might":1035,
         "public":false,
         "tag":"GABA",
         "slogan":"",
         "id":744128593839677958
      },
      "746034084459209223":{  
         "emblem":0,
         "name":"Queen",
         "member_count":1,
         "level":1,
         "military_might":1035,
         "public":false,
         "tag":"QUE",
         "slogan":"",
         "id":746034084459209223
      },
      "750446471312466445":{  
         "emblem":0,
         "name":"Phoenix Inc",
         "member_count":35,
         "level":6,
         "military_might":453369,
         "public":true,
         "tag":"PHOI",
         "slogan":"",
         "id":750446471312466445
      },
      "750446518934594062":{  
         "emblem":11,
         "name":"Australia",
         "member_count":44,
         "level":8,
         "military_might":957211,
         "public":true,
         "tag":"AUST",
         "slogan":"Go Australia",
         "id":750446518934594062
      }
   },
   "server_version":"v7.190.4-master.000000006"
}
```

I tried several jq commands:

```
.alliances_info | .[] |  [{alliance_name: .name, alliance_count: .member_count, alliance_level: .level, alliance_power: .military_might, alliance_tag: .tag, alliance_slogan: .slogan, alliance_id: .id}]
```

or

```
.alliances_info | .. | objects |  [{alliance_name: .name, alliance_c
ount: .member_count, alliance_level: .level, alliance_power: .military_might, alliance_tag: .tag, alliance_slogan: .slog
an, alliance_id: .id}]
```

But Always get a jq error: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 3

I renounce on the object Building in the first command (and built only a Array) it works. But i need that objects. Any tips?

BR
Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i am a idiot (to be here totally clear). I found the reason (and this is normally a nobrainer...). I read the input from a file and the funny thing is that the file is Unicode but no UTF8. after recoding the command is working fine. Thanks for the help.

BR
Timo

Answer (score 0):

Your first query works perfectly well with the given JSON sample.  Perhaps you're invoking jq incorrectly.  If you have the jq program in a file, say select.jq, you'd invoke jq like so:

```
jq -f select.jq sample.json
```

If that doesn't help, then try:

```
jq empty sample.json
```

If that fails, there might be something wrong with the encoding of the JSON.

Comment: Hi Peak, well i know that the first command is working (in jqplay). My problem is that this is not working on jq for Windows. i getting there an jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Your first attempt works for me, but generates one output for JSON value in the input.  That is, I created a file named `so.json` and put in it your JSON from above:

```
{
  "alliances_info": {
    "744085325458334213": {
      "emblem": 3,
⋮
}
```

When I run your program , I get:

```
$ jq '.alliances_info | .[] |  [{alliance_name: .name, alliance_count: .member_count, alliance_level: .level, alliance_power: .military_might, alliance_tag: .tag, alliance_slogan: .slogan, alliance_id: .id}]' so.json
[
  {
    "alliance_name": "wellwell",
    "alliance_count": 1,
    "alliance_level": 1,
    "alliance_power": 1035,
    "alliance_tag": "MELL",
    "alliance_slogan": "",
    "alliance_id": 744085325458334200
  }
]
[
  {
    "alliance_name": "Brave",
⋮
]
```

If you want an array at all, you probably want one array containing all the alliances like this:

```
$ jq '.alliances_info | [ .[] | { alliance_name: .name, alliance_id: .id } ]' so.json
[
  {
    "alliance_name": "wellwell",
    "alliance_id": 744085325458334200
  },
  {
    "alliance_name": "Brave",
    "alliance_id": 744128593839678000
  },
  {
    "alliance_name": "Queen",
    "alliance_id": 746034084459209200
  },
  {
    "alliance_name": "Phoenix Inc",
    "alliance_id": 750446471312466400
  },
  {
    "alliance_name": "Australia",
    "alliance_id": 750446518934594000
  }
]
```

Starting from the left, 
- `.alliances_info` looks in its input object for the field named "alliances_info" and outputs its value
- the `|` next says take the output from the left-hand side and pass those as inputs to the right-hand side.
- right after that first `|`, I have a `[ «jq expressions» ]` which tells `jq` to create one JSON array output for each input; the elements of that array are the outputs of that inner `«jq expressions»`
- that inner expression starts with `.[]` which means to produce one output for each JSON value (ignoring the keys) in the input object. For us, that will be the objects named `"744085325458334213"`, `"744128593839677958"`, …
- The next `|` uses those objects as input and for each, generates a JSON object `{ alliance_name: .name, alliance_id: .id }`

That's why I end up with one JSON array containing 5 JSON objects.

As far as I can tell, you are mostly just renaming a bunch of the fields. For that, you could just do something like this:

```
$ jq --argjson renameMap '{ "name": "alliance_name", "member_count": "alliance_count", "level": "alliance_level", "military_might": "alliance_power", "tag": "alliance_tag", "slog": "alliance_slogan"}' '.alliances_info |= ( . | [ to_entries[] | ( .value |= ( . | [ to_entries[] | ( .key |= ( if $renameMap[.] then $renameMap[.] else . end ) ) ] | from_entries ) ) ] | from_entries )' so.json 
{
  "alliances_info": {
    "744085325458334213": {
      "emblem": 3,
      "alliance_name": "wellwell",
      "alliance_count": 1,
      "alliance_level": 1,
      "alliance_power": 1035,
      "public": false,
      "alliance_tag": "MELL",
      "slogan": "",
      "id": 744085325458334200
    },
    "744128593839677958": {
      "emblem": 0,
      "alliance_name": "Brave",
      "alliance_count": 1,
      "alliance_level": 1,
      "alliance_power": 1035,
      "public": false,
      "alliance_tag": "GABA",
      "slogan": "",
      "id": 744128593839678000
    },
⋮
  },
  "server_version": "v7.190.4-master.000000006"
}
```

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for the Explanation. well it is a Little bit more that renaming (that is the first step of some modification for a database Import). primarly Problem is that the command is working in jqplay but not under jq for Windows.